# $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}|\log_{2}(\log_{3}(\log_{4}(\cos t+a)))|dt$.The smallest integral value of $a$ for which $f(x)$ is increasing $\forall x\in R$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}|\log_{2}(\log_{3}(\log_{4}(\cos t+a)))|dt$.The smallest integral value of $a$ for which $f(x)$ is increasing $\forall x\in R$

---

$f'(x)=|\log_{2}(\log_{3}(\log_{4}(\cos x+a)))|>0$ for the function to be increasing.
$\log_{2}(\log_{3}(\log_{4}(\cos x+a)))>0$ or $\log_{2}(\log_{3}(\log_{4}(\cos x+a)))<0$
$\cos x+a>64$ or $\cos x+a<64$
Am i correct uptil here?I am stuck here.Please help me.

Comment: Is it some rule that "primitive of a positive function is always increasing wherever it is defined"?Any other simple example,can you quote to support this?@Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: I have been really sloppy: as D.A. shows you, $a=6$ is the smallest integer value such that the integrand is *defined*. However, for $a=5$, you have to check whether or not the function is integrable. For example, $\log x$ is integrable at $0$ (and the primitive of $\log x$ is $x \log x - x$).

Answer (score 2):

because of the absolute value we see that $f'(x)=|\log_{2}(\log_{3}(\log_{4}(\cos x+a)))|\geq 0$.

but we need $f(x)$ be defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $f'(x)$ need to be defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for reimann integral to exist:
$$\log_{3}(\log_{4}(\cos x+a)) > 0$$
$$\log_{4}(\cos x+a) > 1 $$
$$\cos x+a > 4 $$
$$a > 5 $$

therefore, the smallest integral value for $a$ that $f(x)$ increasing for all $x$ is 6.